# How to get advertisement link from adView (google admob)?

Tags: android, hyperlink, ads

I use AdMob to create ads on android application.When I touch adView, it will open the web page corresponding to the ad content.So let me ask, I can get the link of the ad currently present on adView not?

```
adView = new AdView (this, AdSize.BANNER, "a1513a0c84c8223");
adView.loadAd (new AdRequest ());
```

How to get the web link of the advertising medium takes about by Current requests.

Comment: I believe you can't. I think when you click on the ad you are redirected to admob server and from there to the ad location. This way they can track clicks.

Comment: i know but i still want to try